# Find and remove attribute on all elements of a certain type

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a script that will search an entire page and remove the attribute `disabled` from all objects of type `button`. What is the best method to accomplish this? Looking for plain JS solutions.

For example I would like to turn this:

```
<button disabled class="foo">My button</button>
```

into:

```
<button class="foo">My button</button>
```

This script will be executed after the page loads.

Comment: I'm going to use this to remove thumbnail spoilers from sports broadcasts that I watch on delay! Seeing a score or players celebrating in a video thumbnail ruins it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(b=>b.removeAttribute('disabled'));
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in vanilla JavaScript without any library. Use `getElementsByTagName()` to get all elements of a given tag, and then iterate through them and use `removeAttribute()` to remove a given attribute. Here is a demo:

```js
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  b[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

```html
<button disabled class="foo">My 1st button</button>
<button disabled class="foo">My 2nd button</button>
<button disabled class="foo">My 3rd button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you need to use values/attributes for individual buttons

```
$('button').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

OR

You can simply use this

```
$('button').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: is there any way to crawl the entire page? I'm trying to build this as a browser extension.

Comment: pasting the second suggestion into the console gives me this error: `TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$('button')', '$' is undefined)`

Comment: Did you embed jQuery into your page?

Comment: This answer requires jQuery, which is not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery you can do `$('button[disabled]').removeAttr('disabled')`