# Is there some way to remove the "hidden" attribute in all elements of a page?

Tags: attributes, hidden, bookmarklet

I've been trying to create a bookmarklet that unhides everything on a webpage, but it hasn't been working. Here's the code I have so far:

```
document.getElementsByTagName(*)[0].removeAttribute("hidden")
```

What do I have to do for it to unhide ALL elements?

**Edit:** I have found a line of code in the question linked below, thanks for helping!

```html
<p>Hi there</p>
<p hidden>This is hidden p text</p>
<b hidden>This is also hidden text with the bold tag</b>
<br><br/>

<button onclick="unhide()">Click Me</button>

<script>
  function unhide() {
    document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(b => b.removeAttribute('hidden'));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you add/remove hidden in <p hidden> with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836397/how-do-you-add-remove-hidden-in-p-hidden-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Find and remove attribute on all elements of a certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041868/find-and-remove-attribute-on-all-elements-of-a-certain-type/49041944)

Best regards

Comment: Thanks! I modified a line of code found there and it unhid everything!